# Mysql Replication not working with Wordpress XMLRPC

Tags: mysql, wordpress, replication, xml-rpc

I have wordpress site using 3 mysql replication. Master-master replication and 1 slave.
Now have problem with the slave. When Master update posting from XMLRPC, the slave is not getting update too. This is happen a few days ago, before that is working fine and beside that at other server that using Master-Master replication is working fine too.

I can't find any error message as If I create new post or update it not from XMLRPC, the replication in slave is working fine.

I don't know what happen before got this problem but as long as I know, the last thing that I did was update wordpress to version 3.4. But if this the cause why at master-master replication still working fine as all site using version 3.4 too?

By the way, I saw at master there were a lot of transfer data from slave, compare from other slave server that using master/slave. About 288MB incoming data from slave.

```
2136K  288M ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       xx.14.xx.107       0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306
272K   14M ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       xx.18.xx.36         0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306
```

---

edit:

I just solve my own problem :D

My configuration are 3 server.
A and B are master-master replication and C is slave-master with A.
My problem is because from XMLRPC server (D) resolve my domain to server B when create/update posting (I'm using single domain) so It's seem can't update slave C if is not from A.
I'm forget that I was moving to new server D too.

I don't know if it's normal that Slave C only can be updated from A if using XMLRPC but at least solve my problem. :D

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your "solution" I can tell you something is wrong with your replication

If A and B are true master-master, then writes done to B replicate to A. If C is a slave to A then *all* writes on A also replicate to C.

I suspect you have your server "server-id" settings in mysql are wrong. I.E. C and B have the same server-id.

It *may* be that your auto_increment_increment isn't set to 2 (the minimum you need with 2 write masters), or that your auto_increment_offset isn't different on each of the write masters. I suspect though if it were either of these your replication would be broke any time you wrote to both of the servers and you'd already see that problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to add log-slave-updates  to A. 
by default MySQL replication doesn't log to the replication log any statements that it received from a master.  whenever you daisy chain replication you need to make sure the server logs these so they'll get sent to it's slaves.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates